# Maven project building but cannot find classes at runtime

Tags: java, maven, gson

I have this pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>suman</groupId>
    <artifactId>suman</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>suman</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and I have this main file:

```
package suman;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.google.code.gson.*;  // can't find this lib


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.toJson(1);            

    }
}
```

and then I install with:

```
$ mvn install -DskipTests
```

and I get this *compile error*:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project suman: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure:  [ERROR]
>   /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/oredoc/test/builds/java/gson/src/main/java/suman/App.java:[5,1]
>   package com.google.code.gson does not exist [ERROR]
>   /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/oredoc/test/builds/java/gson/src/main/java/suman/App.java:[17,9]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class Gson [ERROR]   location:
>   class suman.App [ERROR]
>   /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/oredoc/test/builds/java/gson/src/main/java/suman/App.java:[17,25]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class Gson [ERROR]   location:
>   class suman.App

Does anyone know why it can't find the gson libraries? seems really weird.

Ok so if I change it to:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

then it compiles, but then if I run it with `java -jar`, I get this *runtime error*:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/gson/Gson
>           at suman.App.main(App.java:17) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>           ... 1 more

Comment: ok so if I mport this instead `com.google.gson.*` of this `com.google.code.gson.*` it works, but why is that?

Comment: try maven clean build

Comment: @Deadpool see my comment right above yours, do you get it?

Comment: okay, first thing why do you need `com.google.gson.*` just try importing required import statements

Comment: Java programs have two classpaths - one at compile time and another at runtime. You need to include the `gson` library on your classpath at runtime as well.

Comment: @SeanBright, got it thanks, that was my suspicion, I was running it with: `java -cp target/suman-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar suman.App`, but like you said that wasn't including the gson .jar file, can you add an answer with your best guess on how to include the gson jar file using the command line or CLASSPATH env var?

Comment: In other words, where is the gson jar file lol, I can't find it in my maven project. I assumed maven would know where it stores it so I wouldn't have to manually include it...isn't that the purpose of a build tool like maven lol? maybe I should use a different command other than `java -jar` to run my project? is there a way to run it using mvn?

Comment: @SeanBright thanks Sean that helped a lot, I found an answer and posted it.

Comment: If you want to run the jar, you need to make this jar executable. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your local Maven repository does not have jar file for:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

try to look down from ~/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5 directory.

If there is no jar file like `gson-2.8.5.jar` - simple step delete whole directory.

With next build it will force Maven to try to download that artifact from your defined remote repositories and you will see how it passed.

Either it will download and all will be fine or it will not.

If not - then check your settings.xml (or pom file) about repository from where it can be downloaded ( at least in Maven repository listing (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5) it is  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

If you have that repository defined and you are behind corporate proxy - check your proxy settings for Maven in settings.xml

BTW: at run time you must have all needed jar files in class path as long as you build jar (not war or ear). As alternative with Maven you can build "fat jar" and all classes from all dependencies will be there, but be ready it will be a really big fat jar. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was building my project with

```
$ mvn install -DskipTests
```

and then running it with:

```
$ java -cp target/suman-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar suman.App
```

but instead I should use mvn to run it, like so:

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="suman.App"
```

now it has the right jar files in the classpath. using the plain java command, it didn't know where to find the `com.google.code.gson` jar file.

As an aside, I don't know why this fails to compile:

```
import com.google.code.gson.*;
```

but this succeeds:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

according to the pom.xml file, I would think the former not that latter would be correct.